# Emojis not displayed in the VSCode editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode is not rendering emojis properly, instead is just showing an empty space:

[image]

However, they are getting displayed properly on a page:

[image]

Any idea why this might be happening? OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by uninstalling extension support Emoji for Windows 7

Answer (score -1):

You could use this extension to Visual Studio Code:

https://github.com/Devzstudio/Vscode-Emoji-Snippets

Comment: Installing an extension will not solve this problem